# youtube autoplay is not working with iframe

Tags: php, youtube

i have php function which generate youtube code to display video but auto play is not working properly

```
function get_youtube_embed($youtube_video_id = 0, $auto = 0) {
    $embed_code = "";
    if ($auto == 1) {
        $embed_code = '<iframe width="589" height="342" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $youtube_video_id . '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    }
    else {
        $embed_code = '<iframe width="589" height="342" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $youtube_video_id . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    }
    return $embed_code;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's the syntax for autoplay (`autoplay=1`)? because I don't see any problem in the code. Does the source code get generated correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is alright, try doing it by hand, without Javascript. Most likely that the way to set autoplay is wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the autoplay does not always work in the newer

At the bottom of the embed option section on the youtube site, there is a checkbox allowing you to use the old code. Use this as your base.

Your code should look something like this:

```
$embed_code = '<object width="420" height="345"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $youtube_video_id . '?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $youtube_video_id . '?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="345" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>';
```

see: http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=171780&expand=UseOldEmbedCode#oldcode

Comment: autoplay works, the cause was a typo. I don't think the old embed_code should be used for a number of reasons. flash support being one of them.